# How can I write this code better?

Tags: android

I have this piece of code in my Android app's grid view adapter. Basically what it does is to "fit" the first image in a gridview into a square. The next images are cropped. There are some code omitted before this part.

I think I am repeating a whole bunch of stuff unnecessarily. What's a better way to rewrite this code?

```
    if (position ==0) {
        //set thumbnail URL
        String url = item.get(position).getHDUrl();

        // Trigger the download of the URL asynchronously into the image view.
        Picasso.with(mContext) //
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) //
                .error(R.drawable.error) //
                .tag(view) //
                .fit()
                .into(holder.thumbnail);
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));
        return view;

    } else {
        //set thumbnail URL
        String url = item.get(position).getHDUrl();

        // Trigger the download of the URL asynchronously into the image view.
        Picasso.with(mContext) //
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) //
                .error(R.drawable.error) //
                .tag(view) //
                .into(holder.thumbnail);
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));
        return view;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally create a "PicassoHelper" class, to simply wrap Picasso functions.

Then you could create a function in your new helper class that would accept a bool, indicating whether or not it should use '.fit()' or not.

That way you could shrink your code to:

```
//Get thumbnail URL
String url = item.get(position).getHDUrl();

if (position == 0) {
    // Trigger the download of the URL asynchronously into the image view.
    PicassoHelper.downloadImage(url, view, holder.thumbnail, true);
} else {
    // Trigger the download of the URL asynchronously into the image view.
    PicassoHelper.downloadImage(url, view, holder.thumbnail, false);
}

view.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));
return view;
```

That way you wouldn't have to repeat the same code over and over again whenever you use Picasso.

Comment: This is my answer of choice because it eliminates a lot of repetition on my part. I have a bunch of adapters in my app (different lists and objects). Thanks!

Comment: To add to this...Picasso's RequestCreator object doesn't fulfill the request until `into()` is called, so you should be able to do something like this: `RequestCreator picassoRequest = Picasso.with(activity).load(url)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder);
    if (shouldFit) { picassoRequest.fit(); }
    picassoRequest.into(thumbnail);`  to avoid repetition...not sure how to format that in a comment, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

As the only `.fit()` method is added on `position 0` You have to add only `.fit()` method on `position 0`.

You have to separate the common code form if- else as per its position.

I don't know on `Picaso` Object initialization, you can do like,

```
   //set thumbnail URL
        String url = item.get(position).getHDUrl();
if (position ==0) {
        Picasso.with(mContext) //
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) //
                .error(R.drawable.error) //
                .tag(view) //
                .fit()
                .into(holder.thumbnail);
    } else {
        Picasso.with(mContext) //
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) //
                .error(R.drawable.error) //
                .tag(view) //
                .into(holder.thumbnail);

    }
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));
        return view;
```

As I have doubt over weather `.fit()` will work after you initialize `Picaso` with url and other parameters

You can further enhance like,

```
//set thumbnail URL
     String url = item.get(position).getHDUrl();
     Picasso.with(mContext) //
                    .load(url)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) //
                    .error(R.drawable.error) //
                    .tag(view) //
                    .into(holder.thumbnail);

     if (position ==0) {
            Picasso.fit();
        } 
            view.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));
            return view;
```

Comment: Its amazing how people answer the question, then take content from other  answers.. you have edited and just duplicated my answer..

Comment: @Mayhem - I am just wrapping up my answer and meanwhile you posted. No worries, I would like to upvote for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

i would think more like this??

```
//set thumbnail URL
String url = item.get(position).getHDUrl();

if (position ==0) {

    // Trigger the download of the URL asynchronously into the image view.
    Picasso.with(mContext) //
            .load(url)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) //
            .error(R.drawable.error) //
            .tag(view) //
            .fit()
            .into(holder.thumbnail);
} else {

    // Trigger the download of the URL asynchronously into the image view.
    Picasso.with(mContext) //
            .load(url)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) //
            .error(R.drawable.error) //
            .tag(view) //
            .into(holder.thumbnail);
}
view.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));
return view;
```

Been awhile since i've worked on android apart from snippet testing, the only change also would depend if you can do something like below... Not knowing if Picasso is an object or what not, but yea... you should get the idea of what i mean

```
//set thumbnail URL
String url = item.get(position).getHDUrl();
//This was common in both if else
Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).error(R.drawable.error).tag(view).into(holder.thumbnail);

if (position ==0) {
   // this was only common to the if pos=0
    Picasso.fit();
}
view.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));
return view;
```